# UIView animation block for UILabel in UICollectionViewCell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uianimation

I have custom collectionview cell (item). I have many `UILabels` in each item. Depending on data from server, I want to update the label appropriately. Updating the data by reloading the corresponding item works fine. Code:

```
 isUpdate = YES;
 [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                    [_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:bufferUpdateRow];
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, I check for changes, and if there are any, I want to use animation block, but it seems not working.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellID = @"CellID";

    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Update label content here

  if (isUpdate) {
        _label1.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^(void) {
                _label1.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        } completion:nil];

        isUpdate = NO;
  }
  return cell;
}
```

The label is not flashing red as I want. Instead it just stay clear. If I remove the animation block, the label becomes red (which shows the updating detection works fine). Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the red background is displayed before setting it clear again. One way to achieve this would be to place the animation in the completion block of another one:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^(void) {
     self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^(void) {
        self.view.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you are creating the animation in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. This method is just for initialising the cell and setting up its data, not for animating it.

You'd have better chances implementing `UITableViewDelegate` and put the code inside:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fallen in the same issue.but is may bad...

I am working on iOS14.

1. in collectionViewCell you CAN call animation
2. I missed self.layoutIfNeeded()

(in may sample I make a red label appear from right)

```
final func showSwipeToDeleteAnimated(){
    let W = self.frame.width
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.3, options: []) {
        self.redSwipeToDeleteViewViewWidthConstraint.constant = W
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    } completion: { (_) in
        
    }
}
```